# Cron To download Youtube-dl video in a folder not working with php but same command working with putty command line

Tags: php, cron, putty, cron-task, youtube-dl

When I am trying To access a code that is with a cron using fetch URL :

`nohup youtube-dl -o '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/uploadvideos/1506561898.flv' http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x61ykcu 2> /dev/null & echo $!`

i.e : domain.com is my domain name that i have not mentioned here ...

it is not downloading the specified file.

But when i used the same code in Putty(Shell) it download the file in the mentioned folder with the specified name ...

I don't know why it is not working with cron..

Anyone please help me Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code to the top of the crontab -e file.

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```